# Should I store data in db or should I store it in enum?

Tags: java, sql, spring, rest, service

Data is very small like list of fruits and won't be changed often, also only one service will be using this data and serving to other services, please mention advantage and disadvantage of your approach.

Comment: Why would you do all that overhead running a database to manage a tiny list of fruits? Even if the data can change, I'd just dump it into a text file and be done with it. A DB would just add unnecessary complexity to something that sounds super basic, I'd see no advantage.

Comment: Because there are 10's of similar data set which will be used in similar manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better store it in a database's table.

If you store it in a enum, when you add, change or delete a fruit you have to compile your code again. In case of change, you will have to update all places (tables columns) where this fruit's name is store.

In the database you could opt to save it as a single column table or a two columns table (id, fruit_name).

I will opt the second option. Because if you choose the single column option, and you change a fruit name you will have to change it in all the tables where the fruit name is store (like in enum). A disadvantage with the two columns table is that you will have to make joins with the fruit table to get the fruit name (but make this joins is easy and simple).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how often there should be a change and who needs to change it. If you want the employer to be able to change them easily, you may wanna save them in the db and provide them with an api or some kind of ui so they can change whenever they want easily.
but if you yourself need to update it once each year, I see no necessity that you do not hardcode the thing.

Comment: No, changes are expected once in 3-4 year

Comment: It's fine; but in case you'd like to minimize maintenance needs, you could still use a db based approach